# Rails association primary_key option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, primary-key, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I understand that foreign keys are for specifying when you have a different column name (different than parent child's class name) on the child class. I know what primary keys and foreign keys are and have read the rails documentation on associations several times, but I can't figure out what the primary key option is for.

1) But what is the primary_key option for? How does it change the sql when an association is called?

2) In what instances would you need to specify the primary_key on association?

3) In what instances would you need to specify both the primary_key and foreign_key?

below is an example of specifying the foreign_key option on associations:

```
class User
has_many :texts, foreign_key: :owner_id

end

class Text
belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :owner_id

end


User Table
id| name |

Text Table
id| owner_id |name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I thought more about the SQL and figured it out. You use foreign_key option when your child has a different foreign_key name then your parent's classname_id BUT on your parent table, you are still using ID as your identifier.

```
user table
id|name|age

text table
id|random_id|conversations

select * from user where user.id = text.random_id

select * from text where text.random_id (foreign_key) = account.id (primary key)
```

On the other hand, you use primary_key with foreign_key when you don't want to use id at all to link the relationship.

```
user table
id|userable_id|name|age

text table
id|userable_ss_id|conversations
```

HERE: if you wanted to link the userable_ss_id to userable_id, you would include both primary_key and foreign_key options on both relationships.

```
class User 
has_many :texts, primary_key: :userable_ss_id, foreign_key: :userable_id
end

class Text 
belongs_to :user, primary_key: :userable_ss_id, foreign_key: :userable_id
end
```

Basic rule of thumb:

```
select * from text where text.(foreign_key) = account.(primary key)
```

Answer (score 2):

primary key concerns the main table and foreign key the associated one

U 've used the foreign key correctly. If for isntance User had another primary key than :id u'd have to specify that either.

```
#User
 has_many :texts, primary_key: :uuid, foreign_key: owner_id
```

So you need this options, if you want to have another naming of the keys than rails conventions assume for the main and associated table respectivly

Answer (score 2):

Rails uses convention over configuration.

By convention, all database tables in rails have a primary-key of the `id` column.

If, for some odd reason (eg you've got a legacy database), your table uses a different primary key to `id`... you use the `primary_key` call to tell rails what it is.

By convention, all associations use a foreign-key of `<model>_id` for the foreign key.

If, for some reason, your association uses a different foreign-key to find the associated model - you'd use `foreign_key` to tell rails what it is.

Unlike `primary_key`, using `foreign_key` can be much more common. Especially when you have more than one association using the same table but with different association names.

Comment: ok, i know most of this but why would you need to specify a primary_key directly on an association? can you describe the change in sql that occurs when i specify the primary_key

Comment: not easily... again it comes down to default behaviours that need to change. I'd guess that any default ordering by id would change to default ordering by whatever the primary-key field is... that if you do a find on an association, the sql that is built will use the primary-key column instead of id etc